# How to authenticate user email by sending a verification code using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jwt, sendgrid

I want to send a verification code to the registered Email ID of the user during signup. All the tutorials I found send a verification link using sendgrid API.

Is there any way I this could be done using a verification code instead?

Comment: https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-create-a-signup-confirmation-email-with-node-js-c2fea602872a

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it by yourself.

- in the user schema in the DB you need a boolean place for isAuthenticated and a string place for the auth code.
- generate some code, if you're working with nodejs UUID package for NPM is a great package.
- when a user is registered - save false by default, generate the code and:

  1. save it into the user in the DB
  2. send a mail to the user with a link to the endpoint on your server something like `/:userid/:authcode`
- on the server - build this endpoint, select the user from the DB by the ID you got on the parameter, check if the code you got on the param is the same as the one saved in the user you just selected, and if so - update the user to true
- last thing - on login - check if the auth is true, and if not - send a specific error so you can catch it on the client and display a nice detailed error message

Comment: Can you suggest a way so that auth code remains valid only for some time?

Comment: setTimeout for X amount of time and then just make the code in the DB undefine, so if the user arrive after the expiration date its just not be the same code anymore

Comment: Or event better - add timestamp property to the auth code, and then check against it. It's better because setTimeout will stop if you reload the server so it possible that the auth code will never be deleted so the user will be able to logging forever with the same auth code. If you chack the timestamp of the code it'll never happen

Comment: @YosiLeibman at point 2., firstly, what would be the best way to send the email? secondly, how can you ensure this email is encrypted so that a man-in-the-middle attack won't snatch your unique code?

Comment: If you're using node js there's a package called nodemailer. Check it out